# Sculpt Brush Orientation weird, scaled on an axis

Tags: sculpt

[image]

Dont know how to fix. Top of mesh works fine, its the sides.

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: Did you Apply (Ctrl A) the scale in object mode before sculpting?